# How to make bitcoin hd wallet in typescript?

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets, javascript

I am trying to create HD wallet for bitcoin.

I have developed an Ethereum wallet, but I am having a hard time making a Bitcoin wallet.

In my case, I am developing a server using Golang and Typescript.

Is there a best practice to make a bitcoin wallet using Typescript or Golang?

I'd appreciate it if you could let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paul Miller has created a number of modern typescript libraries to help with this:

- https://github.com/paulmillr/scure-bip39
- https://github.com/paulmillr/scure-bip32
- https://github.com/paulmillr/micro-btc-signer

I've also created a small gist to help you get started:

https://gist.github.com/aulneau/2f5aad7030e046fb6b557a3871231d72

High level overview:

- we generate a mnemonic from `scure-bip39`
- convert the mnemonic to a master seed (via same lib)
- use `scure-bip32` to create the hd node
- define our paths (in this case, bip84)
- generate nodes with the receive and change paths
- derive children nodes
- get the witness pubkey hash address for each node

Hope this helps!! let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Hi aulneau, while these links seem useful, this answer could get into the main question of the asker a bit more.

Comment: Thanks @Murch, updated my answer with an example implementation :)

Comment: Excellent work! Welcome to Bitcoin Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer! It helps a lot!